# API to get information about a URL

Tags: web-services, api, url

What APIs exist to return information/statistics about a URL.

I expect it to expand the url if it is shortened, get sharing statistics(number of shares likes tweets) and get some information about the content it points to (is it an image, a file, a web page).

*PS: I'm not sure if it's the right place to ask this kind of question.. *

Comment: Do you want this information about every URL, or only certain kinds of URL? Do you have some reason to believe that this information exists for every URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can get social sharing data for a URL at http://sharedcount.com/ they got an API too.